# Unexpected output when adding items to list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

This is fairly straghtforward code and it isn't doing what I want it to do. What is wrong?

```
In [63]: c = [[]]*10

In [64]: c
Out[64]: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

In [65]: c[0]
Out[65]: []

In [66]: c[0] += [1]

In [67]: c
Out[67]: [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Expected output is `[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a classic Python pitfall.

```
c = [[]]*10
```

creates a list with 10 items in it. Each of the 10 items in the *same exact list*. So modifying one item modifies them all.

To create 10 independent lists, use

```
c = [[] for i in range(10)]
```